# How to draw this directed graph with tikz

Tags: tikz-arrows, graphs

I am new using Tikz, and I am trying to know how to draw graphs, my try is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[y=.4cm, x=.4cm,font=\normalsize]
\draw (0,5)  --  (1,2);
\draw (1,2)  --  (2.3,0.42) ;
\draw (5,0) --  (2.3,0.42) ;
\draw (9,2)  --  (10,5);
\draw (7.3,9.4)  --  (5,10);
\draw (9,8)  --  (7.3,9.4);
\draw (10,5)  --  (9,8);
\draw (5,10)  --  (2.3,9.4);
\draw (0,5)  --  (0.7,7);
\draw (0.9,7.7)  --  (2.3,9.5);
\draw (5,0)  --  (7.3,0.42);
\draw (7.3,0.42)  --  (9,2);
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (0,5) circle (2pt) node[anchor=east] {10};
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (5,0) circle (2pt) node[anchor=north] {7};
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (5,10) circle (2pt) node[anchor=south] {1};
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (10,5) circle (2pt)node[anchor=west] {4};
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (9,2) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west] {5};
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (9,8) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west] {3};
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (1,2) circle (2pt) node[anchor=east] {9};
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (7.3,0.42) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west] {6};
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (7.3,9.4) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west] {2};
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (2.3,9.4) circle (2pt) node[anchor=south] {n};
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (2.3,0.42) circle (2pt) node[anchor=north] {8};
\filldraw[fill=white!40,draw=white!80] (1.7,7.5) circle (2pt) node[anchor=east] {\dots};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and it gives me something similar to what I want, but I only need that the graph is directed but when I put something like:

```
\draw \[->\](7.3,9.4)  --  (5,10);
```

It allways give errors. I have tryied to install other packages and user other compilators (TeXworks,TeXmaker and Overleaf) but I haven't managed to fix this. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The errors may come from `\[...\]` instead of `[...]`, i.e. try `\draw \[->\](7.3,9.4)  --  (5,10);`. Yet you can simplify the graph a lot.

Comment: Yes! I know it can be simplified a lot, I am new at this and trying to learn. Actually it worked with       \draw \[ latex-\]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a proposal to simplify things.

1. A `\foreach` loop helps to avoid repetition.
2. Then polar coordinates are used. In `(120:5)` `120` denotes the angle and `5` the radius. In the loop, the angles are `{120-\X*360/12}`, i.e. clockwise in steps of `360/12=30` degrees.
3. The labels are attached at the same angles, `label={120-\X*360/12}:` makes sure that they are "outside".

One may condense the code further but then it might become even harder to understand.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=.4cm, x=.4cm,font=\normalsize,>=latex]
\foreach \X [remember=\X as \LastX] in {0,...,10}
 {\ifnum\X=0
  \node [circle,fill=black!40,label=120:$n$,inner sep=2pt](X\X) at (120:5){};
 \else
  \node [circle,fill=black!40,label={120-\X*360/12}:$\X$,inner sep=2pt](X\X) at
  ({120-\X*360/12}:5){};
  \draw[black!80,->]  (X\LastX) -- (X\X);
 \fi}
 \node[rotate={30+360/12}]  (X11) at ({120+360/12}:5) {$\cdots$};
 \draw[black!80,->]  (X10) -- (X11);
 \draw[black!80,->]  (X11) -- (X0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: WOW, it is amazing, thanks a lot!!! I wish I could understand everything there, but I will try. Thanks

Comment: @J.Rodriguez You're welcome! This site is full of examples. I added some explanations for what I did.